# How to take screenshot of a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Say for example i have a div with image source

```
<div>
<p class="row">With custom CSS</p>
<img src="/images/midhun.jpg">
</div>
```

On button click i need to open this image screen shot in another div

Can you tell the steps to take the screen shot of that image

Comment: Why the screenshot, why not copy the image directly?

Comment: What do you mean by take the screen shot? do you mean copy/show that image inside another div?

Comment: What do you believe a screenshot is? - normally we would say that it is a pixel by pixel capture of the stuff shown on screen. That requires access to the video output, or memory. Javascript cannot do that.

Comment: copy the html to another div using jquery

Comment: What i meant is i should get the image copy of <p>tag too.Not the image only but all the contents as image ..

Comment: imagin <p>MIDHUN</p> can i get the screenshot of this <p>?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you want to show the `image` in other `div`.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-XOGfvAHr7HQ/UvoUItkZMZI/AAAAAAAAHJk/IJz5JcUB9dw/w520-h274-no/scopes_in_directives.png" />
</div>
<div id="copy">
</div>
<button id="myButton">Click</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#copy').html($('#main').html());
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/uapf99nt/

Comment: `Assuming, you want to show the image in other div.`

Comment: What i meant is i should get the image copy of <p>tag too.Not the image only but all the contents as image ..

Comment: `contents as image`? or HTML

Comment: Exactly Tushar ,all the content as image

Comment: Imagine i am having a table ,with 3 td .one of the td is having qr code,so i need to take the screenshot of that table too.So please tell the steps to take the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take any screenshot. The image is already loaded, so you can just show the same image again:

HTML

```
<div id="originalDiv">
   <img src="/images/midhun.jpg">
</div>
<div id="secondDiv">
   <img src="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#secondDiv { display:none }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
    var img = $('#originalDiv > img').attr('src');
    $('#secondDiv > img').attr('src', img).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

look here. it attempts to render a part of the dom, into an image

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: After _What i meant is i should get the image copy of <p>tag too.Not the image only but all the contents as image .._ comment, your previous answer was actually right ;)

Comment: true, but a bit provocative.. This is more useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6FZkk/1/) to take a screenshot..

```
$(function() { 
$("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```